# Unable to get png file saved if I tried to process the image immediately

Tags: node.js

I am trying to fetch the image remote then process it by node-tesseract. Code following:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
request.get('http://cn.bing.com/s/a/hpc18.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('bing.png'));
```

Code above is doing well and the png file will be saved correctly.

Then I want to process the png by tesseract ocr(node binding)

```
tesseract.process('bing.png', options, function (err, text) {
         //do something
});
```

After running all code above, I found that the text is null. Then i checked the picture, the png file didn't generate correctly - it's an empty file.

Anyone could help? I tried to sleep some time between those two parts but it didn't work.  Why even the png file wasn't generated?

Regards,

Lyu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this out:

```
var fs      = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var tesseract = require('tesseract');

request.get({url: 'http://cn.bing.com/s/a/hpc18.png', encoding: 'binary'}, function (err, response, body) {
  fs.writeFile("bing.png", body, 'binary', function(err) {
    if(err)
      console.log(err);
    else
        tesseract.process('bing.png', options, function (err, text) {
            //do something
        });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. It helps me a lot. After putting process function in the callback the image was generated correctly.  But tesseract still can't read the file correctly(always returns null).   If I run the process directly it can read the text well. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Are you familiar with tesseract?

{ [Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "tesseract captchas/
x7XpRnnr.png C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\node-tesseract-ec4fe582-d244-4
fca-9782-a43c117f37b2 -l eng -psm 3"
'tesseract' �����ڲ����ⲿ���Ҳ���ǿ����еĳ���
���������ļ���
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c "tesseract captchas/x7XpRnnr.png C:
\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\node-tesseract-ec4fe582-d244-4fca-9782-
a43c117f37b2 -l eng -psm 3"' }

I just output the error log

Comment: Would you please let me know how to configure tesseract on windows?

killed: false, code: 1, signal: null, cmd: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c "tesseract captchas/x7XpRnnr.png C: \\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\node-tesseract-ec4fe582-d244-4fca-9782- a43c117f37b2 -l eng -psm 3"' }

What does those mean?